# Converting string to binary representation in python

Tags: python

I want to create binary values for words based on their content of vowels and consonants, where vowels receive a value of '0' and consonants get a value of '1'.

For example, 'haha' would be represented as 1010, hahaha as 101010.

```
common_words = ['haha', 'hahaha', 'aardvark', etc...]

dictify = {}

binary_value = []

#doesn't work
for word in common_words: 
    for x in word:
        if x=='a' or x=='e' or x=='i' or x=='o' or x=='u':
            binary_value.append(0)
            dictify[word]=binary_value
        else:
            binary_value.append(1)
            dictify[word]=binary_value
```

-With this I am getting too many binary digits in the resulting dictionary:

```
>>>dictify
{'aardvark': [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,...}
```

desired output:

```
>>>dictify
{'haha': 1010,'hahaha': 101010, 'aardvark': 00111011}
```

I am thinking of a solution that doesn't involve a loop within a loop...

Comment: Where does `each` or `number_value` come from?

Comment: There is no solution that doesn't use two loops.

Comment: `dictify = {w:"".join('0' if c in 'aeiouAEIOU' else '1' for c in w) for w in common_words}`

Comment: Your desired output isn't really possible-- `00111011` won't work as an integer because there's no way to preserve the initial zeroes.  You could use a string or a list.

Comment: Please post your actual code. The code you posted can't work `each` and `binary_value` are never set.

Comment: sorry I had some variables misnomered. edited.

Comment: @PeterMichealLacey-Bordeaux for some definition of *loop* that's true, but my answer contains only string.translate and a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've posted doesn't work because all words share the same `binary_value` list. (It also doesn't work because `number_value` and `each` are never defined, but we'll pretend those variables said `binary_value` and `word` instead.) Define a new list for each word:

```
for word in common_words:
    binary_value = []
    for x in word:
        if x=='a' or x=='e' or x=='i' or x=='o' or x=='u':
            binary_value.append(0)
            dictify[word]=binary_value
        else:
            binary_value.append(1)
            dictify[word]=binary_value
```

If you want the output to look like `00111011` rather than a list, you'll need to make a string. (You could make an int, but then it would look like `59` instead of `00111011`. Python doesn't distinguish "this int is base 2" or "this int has 2 leading zeros".)

```
for word in common_words:
    binary_value = []
    for x in word:
        if x.lower() in 'aeiou':
            binary_value.append('0')
        else:
            binary_value.append('1')
    dictify[word] = ''.join(binary_value)
```

Answer (score 2):

user2357112 explains your code. Here is just another way:

```
>>> common_words = ['haha', 'hahaha', 'aardvark']
>>> def binfy(w):
        return "".join('0' if c in 'aeiouAEIOU' else '1' for c in w)

>>> dictify = {w:binfy(w) for w in common_words}
>>> dictify
{'aardvark': '00111011', 'haha': '1010', 'hahaha': '101010'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a job for translation tables. Assuming your input strings are all ASCII (and it seems likely or the definition of exactly what is a vowel gets fuzzy), you can define a translation table this way*:

```
# For simplicity's sake, I'm only using lowercase letters
from string import lowercase, maketrans
tt = maketrans(lowercase, '01110111011111011111011111')
```

With the above table, the problem becomes trivial:

```
>>> 'haha'.translate(tt)
'1010'
>>> 'hahaha'.translate(tt)
'101010'
>>> 'aardvark'.translate(tt)
'00111011'
```

Given this solution, you can build dictify very simply with a comprehension:

```
dictify = {word:word.translate(tt) for word in common_words} #python2.7
dictify = dict((word, word.translate(tt)) for word in common_words) # python 2.6 and earlier
```

*This can also be done with Python 3, but you have to use bytes instead of strings:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
tt = b''.maketrans(bytes(ascii_lowercase, 'ascii'), b'01110111011111011111011111')
b'haha'.translate(tt)
...
```